# Does a company gain ownership of code if it's done on a company computer but not on company time?

Tags: projects

Obviously, all code written on company time on the company's computer goes to the company. But does this also apply to off hours?

If so, to what extent?
If I download a 1,000 file project and modify 1 file. Do they own the whole project or just that one file?

Basically, after watching Silicon Valley it got me thinking

EDIT: I just read the contract and it says nothing about it in the contract. Also, I'm not a full time employee there, just part time(28h/w).

Comment: Sounds like something the old employee handbook / contract could answer. Have you had a look there?

Comment: @Kozaky hmm doesn't have anything written about that in my companies rules

Comment: What about your contract ? if its silent  then "custom and practice"  will be how that's decided in the UK/USA the assumption is that employers do own work "related" to your job

Comment: Is “company time” defined in the contract?

Comment: Prior to my employment starting, I had to get my employer to alter my contract to allow me to work on my own time and retain the IP (intellectual property). Normally if you don't read the fine print you will have signed this right away when you started working.

Comment: It's a legal question and the answer will probably depend on the country you work in. Btw, if you're from the US, you may want to watch Silicon Valley. I remember they discussed a similar question in one episode. (Of course you shouldn't base your opinion on such a serious matter on what was said in a series, but you actually asked your question on an internet forum, so...)

Comment: A lawyer will have a definitive answer, but I feel like it's generally unwise to do *anything* "personal" on a company computer.  If the company suddenly decides to reclaim the device, personal information might be lost to you, or left behind for others to find even if you have a backup / online storage.  It's just better if the two remain separate, regardless of what's "allowed."

Comment: The reason why company policy may not explicitly cover personal code you created on company laptops is because it may instead simply forbid use of company laptops for personal uses. Might be worth checking for that, too. It's hard to discuss ownership of something you weren't supposed to create in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

As well as using your work-provided computer for developing personal projects on, you're also (I'm guessing) using company provided software to do so (which is licensed to your company and not yourself).

In effect, you're using company provided resources to develop code that doesn't benefit the company you work for (it doesn't matter if it's one line of code to 10,000).

You can see where this is heading now....

Whether the code can be considered property of you or the company is open to interpretation of the relevant employment contract and software licenses.  How your company views your activity is something else.

Comment: Don't ever mix company resources with your own.  Learn to use portable apps and even then, you still need very clear boundaries.

Answer (score 5):

**Depends completely on your employment contract**.  In the IT world, it's not uncommon for companies to claim ownership of *everything* you create, even outside office hours and on your personal equipment, if it relates to or could potentially compete with the company's business.  For example, while I don't work there I gather this is standard for Amazon, and good luck finding a line of work they're not somehow involved in: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1132ffc6f32ca6416cd92aa82009d3de